# Problem with using dictionaries inside f string

Tags: python, f-string

I'm using f string format to do some printing. The interpreter throws a syntax error when I use a value from a dictionary.

```
print(f'value = {mydict['key']}')
```

Why is that, how can I overcome it?

Comment: Try `print(f"value = {mydict['key']}")`

Comment: The f-string ends at the second apostrophe, and the rest of the line, `key']}')`, isn't valid.

Comment: The double quotation mark trick didn't work. I tried it both ways.
Yes I understand whats happening.  But this is frustrating cause f-string has been my favourite formatting way.

Comment: Are there any other lines of codes that you are running? What's the exact error that is thrown? Using the double quote `"` and single quote `'` should work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works just fine. Make sure you're separating your use of single and double quotes! (If the outer quotes are double quotes, make the quotes around "key" single quotes, or vice-versa)

```py
mydict["key"] = 5   
print(f"value = {mydict['key']}")
```

> value = 5

---

Followup for OP's comment:
Printing a list isn't a problem either!

```py
mydict["key"] = ["test1", "test2"]   
print(f"value = {mydict['key']}")
```

> value = ['test1', 'test2']

Comment: I'm trying it. Not working

            print(f"Epoch={epoch} , Batch={step:2d}/{num_batches:2d}, DC Accuracy={dc_metric.result().numpy():1.3f}, "
                  f"LP Loss={hist['lp_loss_sou']:1.5f}", end='\r')

Error:TypeError: unsupported format string passed to list.__format__

Comment: It worked! My dictionary was returning a list causing troubles. I specified one entry of that list and it worked. Thanks

Comment: @AlexDeft A list works as well, so I suspect something else is the issue...

Comment: No it doesn't work! Well, it worked for you because you never specified the format. But in my case I did this: {mydict["key"]:2d} Notice the :2d. This doesn't work for lists. That's why on my end it didn't work when the dictionary returned a list.

Comment: Thats a different issue from the syntax error you mentioned in the question :)

Comment: @AlexDeft PS, in the future, you should always try to include the actual code and the actual error message!